# OpenSSL - BIGNUM check issue

Tags: c, openssl, endianness

I use OpenSSL 1.0.2k to handle private and public key on a software, and I have some issue with a few OSes (linux-s390, aix power, HPUX IA64), on 64-bits arch only.

It's not so troublesome, but it bothers me.
I get a RSA* structure from a buffer (DER data), and I just check the RSA public exponent to ensure it's odd.
It works on every OSes, except the three above : it seems the RSA->e is even (and, obviously, it's not)

Here is the BIGNUM structure :

```
struct bignum_st {
    BN_ULONG *d;
    int top;
    int dmax;
    int neg;
    int flags;
};
```

When debugging, I saw that on a functional OS, d[0] == 65537, d[1] == 0. On a no functional OS, d[0] == 0, d[1] == 65537.
BN_is_odd is a macro :

```
# define BN_is_odd(a)        (((a)->top > 0) && ((a)->d[0] & 1))
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>

int get_key(const unsigned char *buf, int len) {
    RSA *rsa = d2i_RSA_PUBKEY(NULL, &buf, len);
    if (rsa != NULL) {
        if (rsa->e != NULL) {
            printf("BN : <%s> (hex) -- <%s> (dec)\n", BN_bn2hex(rsa->e), BN_bn2dec(rsa->e));
            if (BN_is_odd(rsa->e) == 0) {
                printf("Error : RSA public exponent is even\n");
            } else {
                printf("RSA public exponent is OK.\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }
        RSA_free(rsa);
    } else {
        printf("Error : RSA is NULL\n");
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    const unsigned char data[] = { 0x30, 0x81, 0x9f, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86, 0xf7, 0x0d, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x03, 0x81, 0x8d, 0x00, 0x30, 0x81, 0x89, 0x02, 0x81, 0x81, 0x00, 0xd6, 0x70, 0x5d, 0x67, 0xf2, 0xe1, 0x34, 0x82, 0xd5, 0x2d, 0x79, 0xdd, 0x42, 0x55, 0x41, 0xaf, 0x0c, 0xc2, 0xb4, 0xb0, 0x94, 0xc6, 0xa0, 0x40, 0x54, 0x2e, 0x0f, 0xa5, 0x12, 0x3d, 0x43, 0x96, 0x13, 0x2d, 0x17, 0x50, 0xe5, 0x9a, 0x5a, 0x6e, 0x99, 0xc7, 0xd2, 0x63, 0x4c, 0xcd, 0x57, 0xcb, 0x57, 0x7e, 0x1e, 0x5f, 0x97, 0xaa, 0xbd, 0xe5, 0xc0, 0x98, 0xd9, 0x07, 0x52, 0xdc, 0x27, 0xa4, 0x19, 0xb2, 0x81, 0x5d, 0xd5, 0x03, 0x5c, 0xd2, 0xb3, 0xb8, 0x28, 0xaa, 0xd7, 0xaf, 0x02, 0x08, 0x1c, 0x6c, 0xc2, 0xa4, 0x6c, 0x41, 0xd3, 0xa6, 0xae, 0x51, 0x69, 0xb7, 0xd5, 0x79, 0xb8, 0x62, 0x68, 0x9e, 0xa9, 0x44, 0x8e, 0xbe, 0xb1, 0x2e, 0x1a, 0x3c, 0x4b, 0x21, 0x7b, 0x7d, 0x36, 0xf0, 0x97, 0x98, 0x81, 0x63, 0xa6, 0xfa, 0xf8, 0x28, 0x22, 0x72, 0xfe, 0x16, 0xa8, 0x16, 0x89, 0xbb, 0x02, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01 }; /* A DER buffer, valid with openssl rsa -pubin -in <file> -inform DER */
    return get_key(data, sizeof data);
}
```

On most system, I get the output "RSA public exponent is OK". However, on some others, I got "RSA public exponent is even". The BIGNUM printed is correct (010001 -- 65537).

I understand why the BIGNUM is considered as even. But why is there a leading zero on those three OSes ? (no problem on those OSes with 32-bits, though).
Any thought appreciated on that :)

Comment: You seem to have discovered the concept of _endian_-ness: these platforms are _big endian_, x86 and amd64 are _little endian_. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: I also faced this Problem in AIX, and involved the IBM Dev Team. They confirmed
the BUG and now i need to know how you generated this DER Buffer?
"openssl rsa -pubin -in <file> -inform DER" on an RSA key seems not to work.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond I'm like 2 years late but hey, better than nothing... Yes, I'm familiar with endianness. I just wasn't expecting a bug like that in OpenSSL -- since the BN_is_odd() function does not work on such architecture. Thanks for your reply anyway.

Comment: Tried on AIX6.1 with OpenSSL-1.1.1k, it doesn't show the problem. Mind you, type `RSA` became opaque, function `RSA_get0_e` returns _e._

Comment: Good to know. We're still stuck with OpenSSL 1.0.2 since 1.1.1 does not have FIPS support, unfortunately. Thanks for your help, and sorry for the... Well, let's say "late" reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, it's because you have compiled 64-bit executable with OpenSSL-header-files
meant for 32-bit.

To be precise, it is `opensslconf.h` which contains one the following two parts
(first for 32-bit, second for 64-bit):

```
181  /* Only one for the following should be defined */
182  #undef SIXTY_FOUR_BIT_LONG
183  #undef SIXTY_FOUR_BIT
184  #define THIRTY_TWO_BIT
185  #endif
```

or

```
181  /* Only one for the following should be defined */
182  #define SIXTY_FOUR_BIT_LONG
183  #undef SIXTY_FOUR_BIT
184  #undef THIRTY_TWO_BIT
185  #endif
```

To make it compatible with both 32 and 64-bit, edit it this way:

```
181  /* Only one for the following should be defined */
182  #undef SIXTY_FOUR_BIT_LONG
183  #undef SIXTY_FOUR_BIT
184  #undef THIRTY_TWO_BIT
185  #if defined(__64BIT__)
186  #define SIXTY_FOUR_BIT_LONG
187  #else
188  #define THIRTY_TWO_BIT
189  #endif
190  #endif
```

http://lzsiga.users.sourceforge.net/aix-linking.html#Q0044

Comment: Oh, I did not think about that ! We indeed had an issue discovered a few days ago, it seems our OpenSSL worked by chance -- the opensslconf.h used was the one created for aix 32 bits... For all OSes we support (solaris, linux, hpux...).